# Project Euler 25 infinite loop

Tags: java

I'm working on the Project Euler [25](http://projecteuler.net/problem=25). I worked out how to do Fibonacci and I'm using `BigInteger`. My program seems to be running for an infinite loop (or so I think). Could it be that it is taking a long time or is it actually going into infinite loop? Can someone point me in the correct direction so I can fix it?

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Problem25 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getTerm(0);
    }

    public static void getTerm(int start) {

        BigInteger var = BigInteger.ZERO;
        BigInteger var2 = BigInteger.valueOf(start);

        int counter = 0;

        while(true) {

            BigInteger temp = var.add(var2);
            var = var2;
            var2 = temp;
            counter++;

            if(var.toString().length() > 1000) {
                System.out.print(counter);
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

EDIT: Sorry people. I thought, I had break; but thanks for your responses.

Comment: while(true) i_break_for_nothing();

Comment: Note that 1000 is allowed as well, so change it to: `if(len >= 1000)` instead of `if(len > 1000)`.

Comment: Note that the two start number of fibonacci are 1 and 1. So change it to: `var = BigInteger.ONE; var2 = BigInteger.ONE`;

Comment: Project Euler is a series of programming challenges which involve mathematics. Bear in mind that the person asking the question does not *necessarily* want hints or tips beyond their specific question. Basically be careful of spoilers. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have no condition for terminating the loop:

```
while(true) { // << always true ;P

    BigInteger temp = var.add(var2);
    var = var2;
    var2 = temp;
    counter++;

    if(var.toString().length() > 1000) {
        System.out.print(counter);
    }
}
```

So it is an infinite loop. You have two (or even more) options:

- Specify in the `while(statement)` what is the condition to continue with the loop for another round.
- Add some `break;` statement to stop the loop if a certain condition is evaluated as true.

Answer (score 3):

`getTerm(0);`

Shouldn't this be `getTerm(1);`?

Also, MByD's answer is right; but this is also a critical problem. Without changing this, your program will never output.

Comment: +1 the `while(true)` shouted too me PROBLEM. But you are right as well.

Comment: it's not about sportsmanship :) it's simply the fact that I usually miss the underlying logical problem and stick with the easy-to-see problem (e.g. I didn't even read the OP's algorithm)

Comment: Yes, this is the actual problem. The fact that the loop never ends is almost irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

1) Yes, you have an infinite loop. Put a **break;** statement right after your print().

2) Try looking for the first, oh, two-digit term. Or three-digit. Baby steps are good with a lot of the Project Euler problems.

3) Run it under a debugger, and watch what's happening. Combines well with 2).

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `getTerm(0)`, so initially `var` and `var2` are both zero. Then you add `var2` to `var` which is still zero, etc., so both `var` and `var2` stay zero and you never make any progress. I think you meant `getTerm(1)`, which should correctly generate the Fibonacci sequence.

And of course, you probably want to `break` out of the loop once you've found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just print every value until a value with 1000 digits is found? There won't be that many anyway because the numbers grow with the golden ration on average.

And as stated elsewhere, add a stopcondition:

```
if(var.toString().length() > 1000) {
    break;
}
```

Comment: Please no. Why `System.exit(0)`? it's cleaner to use break.

Comment: Actually, it will finish faster than I could say "long". But yeah, problem on Euler should not be solved by pure brute force.

Comment: yeah break is cleaner. I was just thinking in terms of getting the result for that particular euler challenge. but then you wouldn't even need a method.

Comment: If not by brute force, then you can say with high, but not complete, certainty, that the term is in the neighborhood of `Math.log(1e1000)/Math.log(phi)+1.67` where phi = golden ratio

Comment: Brute force solutions are perfectly okay. The challenge is to come up with solutions that run in under one minute. For many of the early problems, brute force meets the need and takes little of your own time to design. The more complex problems are not practical to solve with brute force and take more time to design. One of the hidden lessons of the Euler Project is how to make effective use of your own time. I do not deny that it is also fun and interesting to find solutions which run in much less time than one minute, but that is more of an extra credit exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Since `true` is always true, your loop will continue running forever unless you manually terminate it. Use `break;` for this. With your implementation, I think you should place it right after the line `System.out.print(counter)`

Comment: as this will end the loop as soon as the fibonacci number has more than 1000 digits

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
while( !isGood() ) {
    ...
}
```

instead of

```
while(true) {
    ...
    if ( isGood() ) {
       break;
    }
}
```

Here are **3 solutions** that use the approach above (from slow to fast):

**1)** Generate all Fibonacci numbers until the condition is satisfied. Count the digits using division by 10. Time: **6625 ms**

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class P25 {

    final static int N = 1000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int result = getTheFirstIndexHavingTheSpecifiedNumberOfDigits(N);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    // similar performance if you use an "aux" variable
    private static int getTheFirstIndexHavingTheSpecifiedNumberOfDigits(int n) {
        BigInteger a = BigInteger.ONE;
        BigInteger b = BigInteger.ONE;
        int i = 1;
        while ( hasLessThanSpecifiedNumberOfDigits(a, n) ) {
            b = b.add(a);
            a = b.subtract(a);
            i++;
        }
        return i;
    }

    private static boolean hasLessThanSpecifiedNumberOfDigits(BigInteger x, int n) {
        return getNumberOfDigits(x) < n;
    }

    private static int getNumberOfDigits(BigInteger x) {
        int numberOfDigits = 0 ;
        while ( x.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) > 0 ) {
            numberOfDigits++;
            x = x.divide(BigInteger.TEN);
        }
        return numberOfDigits;
    }

}
```

**2)** Generate all Fibonacci numbers until the condition is satisfied. Count the digits using the length of the string. Time: **783 ms**

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class P25 {

    final static int N = 1000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int result = getTheFirstIndexHavingTheSpecifiedNumberOfDigits(N);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static int getTheFirstIndexHavingTheSpecifiedNumberOfDigits(int n) {
        BigInteger a = BigInteger.ONE;
        BigInteger b = BigInteger.ONE;
        int i = 1;
        while ( hasLessThanSpecifiedNumberOfDigits(a, n) ) {
            b = b.add(a);
            a = b.subtract(a);
            i++;
        }
        return i;
    }

    private static boolean hasLessThanSpecifiedNumberOfDigits(BigInteger x, int n) {
        return getNumberOfDigits(x) < n;
    }

    private static int getNumberOfDigits(BigInteger x) {
        return x.toString().length();
    }

}
```

**3)** Store the lowest `BigInteger` that has 1000 digits ( 10^999 ). Generate all Fibonacci numbers and compare them with the computed number. Time: **19 ms**

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class P25 {

    final static int N = 1000;
    final static BigInteger MIN = BigInteger.TEN.pow(N-1);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int result = getTheFirstIndexHavingTheSpecifiedNumberOfDigits(N);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    private static int getTheFirstIndexHavingTheSpecifiedNumberOfDigits(int n) {
        BigInteger a = BigInteger.ONE;
        BigInteger b = BigInteger.ONE;
        int i = 1;
        while ( a.compareTo(MIN) < 0 ) {
            b = b.add(a);
            a = b.subtract(a);
            i++;
        }
        return i;
    }

}
```